# Extracting name/value of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a newbie to Javascript and Nodejs, I am using express and calling the link

> localhost:7080/v1/movies/order/notify/insert?breed=Whippet&age=10

then trying to extract the property name and its corresponding value:

```
  console.log(req.query.breed);     //1
  console.log(req.query.age);       //2
  for (var name in req.query) {     //Extracting property and its value
      console.log(name);            //property name
      console.log(req.query[name]); //3
      console.log(req.query.name);  //4 
  }
```

Could you explain why 3 works fine while **4 gives the value as undefined**? 1 & 2 are also working fine.

Comment: `a.b` is looking for a property called `b`. `a[b]` is looking for a property whose name is defined by the variable `b`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are accessed via string types. When you use `.name`, javascript interprets this as the key of "name" inside the req.query object.

Alternatively, when JavaScript uses `[name]`, the string value associated with that variable is used instead of the variable name itself.

General rule of thumb: When using JavaScript variables to lookup object values, always use bracket notation. `[name]`

Answer (score 0):

the reason #3 works is because:

```
  for (var name in req.query) {     //Extracting property and its value

      console.log(req.query[name]); //3

  }
```

'name' here is a reference to the "key" in req.query. There is no key "name" so when you say: req.query.name -- it errors, because query has no key "name", BUT when you iterate over its keys ala...

```
for (var name in req.query)
```

"name" here is just a reference. It 'holds' the reference to the key names as you iterate over the object.

as an example do this:

```
var obj = {
   age: 100,
   year: 1980,
   color: "blue"
}

for (var name in obj) {
   console.log('KEY IS: ', name)
}
```

but, do you notice "obj" does not have a key "name"... so, doing "obj.name" would error.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of the above answers are right, but placing an example in attempt to illustrate this:

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(foo);

for(i in foo)
console.log(i);

for(i in foo)
console.log(foo[i]);

for(i in foo)
console.log(foo.i);
```

The key contention here is between foo[i] and foo.i
'i' in foo[i] have special meaning in the iterator loop. And the value of i is equal to the iterated entry.
So when we run through the object, in each iteration, 'i' will hold the entry, so foo[i] works.

'i' in foo.i has no special meaning in the iterator loop. 'i' is not treated as a variable, instead, as a known, named attribute of the container object foo. The 'i' in foo.i and the i in the iterator are different.
As we don't have a field called 'i', it throws error.

Hope this helps.